# URIBuilder setParameter adds + instead of %20 for space

Tags: java, decoding, uribuilder

I'm trying to build a URL using URIBuilder and for some reason I get + instead of %20 for space.

this is my code:

```
            URI uri=null;
            try {
                uri = ub.setScheme("http")
                        .setHost("myalcoholist.com")
                        .setPath("/drink-management/view-drink-json")
                        .setParameter("flavor",(String)params[1])
                        .setParameter("brand",(String)params[2])
                        .setParameter("company",(String)params[3])
                        .build();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                Log.e("url", "could not parse url", e);
                return null;
            }
```

the parameters:

```
params[3] = {java.lang.String@831933398520}"contreau france."
params[2] = {java.lang.String@831933398384}"cointreau"
params[1] = {java.lang.String@831933398256}"orange"
```

the result URL:

```
"GET /drink-management/view-drink-json?flavor=orange&brand=cointreau&company=contreau+france. HTTP/1.1" 200 538 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
```

what do I need to change for the parameters to be properly encoded ?

thanks

Comment: What makes you think `+` *isn't* valid encoding for space in a query parameter? (At least in the HTTP scheme...)

Comment: (Which UriBuilder class is this, by the way? I believe there are multiple ones around...)

Comment: I'm not suggesting that using %20 wouldn't be valid as well, by the way.

Comment: org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is very old, but since it's the first result google gave me and had no answers, here is the way I resolved the problem:

Just use `URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8")` with the String (string being your own string) you want to make this change. This will encode all the characters in UTF-8 in your String to URL format.